# Postgresql 9.3 permission denied for schema when trying to delete a row

Tags: postgresql-9.3, permission-denied, user-permissions

I created a user group called 'common' and a user named 'application'. The script below:

```
CREATE ROLE common NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA portal TO common;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA portal TO common;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA portal TO common;
CREATE ROLE application INHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD 'xxxxxx';
GRANT common TO application;
```

To make sure that permissions have been applied to the user 'application', I performed the following command that returned true:

```
select has_table_privilege ('application', 'portal.noticias', 'delete')
   return: t
select has_schema_privilege ('application', 'portal', 'usage')
   return: t
```

Using the user 'application' you can insert, update and select data in the table 'portal.noticias', however when trying to delete a record the following error occurs:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema portal
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "portal"."noticias" x WHERE "codnoticia" ...                               ^
QUERY:  SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "portal"."noticias" x WHERE "codnoticia" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x
```

**I do not know what I did wrong, but I appreciate any help.**

Comment: How is the table defined? I just tried reproducing the problem with what you have posted, and it worked for me. Maybe the table has an ON DELETE trigger, or something?

Comment: There is not triggers

Comment: I realized that even now trying to erase the record with postgres root user the same error occurs. Now I know that the error is not permission. However, **I have no idea what it is.**

Comment: Add the output of \d+ portal.noticias in psql to your question - and, preferably, add all the SQL needed to reproduce the problem in a new, empty database.

Comment: Thank asjo. To replicate the same situation, I am providing two script files. The first for database creation (http://goo.gl/kIgFC4) and the second for basic operations (http://goo.gl/e9cfCb), particularly the delete.

Comment: When I follow your links, I get a page "Sign in to continue to Google Drive"/"You need permission" - could you put them somewhere public? (Your favourite pastebin site, or perhaps http://lpaste.net/ if you don't have one.)

Comment: (http://www.4shared.com/zip/-pVxIkMwba/DataBase-Test.html)

Comment: That site also ask me to login (with Facebook, Twitter, Google+, or Instagram) or create an account before the file can be downloaded. Please just paste the content into a pastebin - e.g. http://lpaste.net/ or a similar place that does not require login. You could even just include it in the question.

Comment: (http://lpaste.net/130187) (http://lpaste.net/130189)

Comment: It looks like a foreign key check lacks permission to execute, probably because the source and/or destination relation has had its owner changed since creation. The error you are getting is from a foreign key check being fired by the `DELETE`, rather than from the `DELETE` its self.

Comment: Thanks, Craig Ringer. What did I do wrong? And especially, how do I fix this?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos have you got the problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

What is creating problems for you is this constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE portal.Fotos_Noticias ADD CONSTRAINT
fk_FotoNoticia_Noticia FOREIGN KEY (codNoticia)
REFERENCES portal.Noticias (codNoticia) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

If you remove that constraint, your DELETE statement runs as expected. But of course you want the constraint.

The owner of the table is AcadAdmin, but AcadAdmin does not have access to the schema portal:

```
test=# select has_schema_privilege('acadadmin', 'portal', 'usage');
 has_schema_privilege 
----------------------
 f
(1 row)

test=# delete from portal.noticias where codNoticia = 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema portal
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "portal"."noticias" x WHERE "codnoticia" ...
                           ^
QUERY:  SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "portal"."noticias" x WHERE "codnoticia" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x
```

Let's see what happens if we give AcadAdmin access to portal:

```
test=# grant usage on schema portal to AcadAdmin;
GRANT
test=# select has_schema_privilege('acadadmin', 'portal', 'usage');
 has_schema_privilege 
----------------------
 t
(1 row)

test=# delete from portal.noticias where codNoticia = 1;
DELETE 1
test=#
```

Bingo!

I'm not an expert in the intricacies of this, but I guess there is a reason for why this happens.